# Recursive async/await request doesn't return to calling function

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await

I'm doing a recursive request with `async/await` whenever the received response has `length === 0`. The problem is that when some request returns the desired data, the `resolve(data);` part of the promise doesn't seem to work.

So, in my code, I have reached the point where I get to make multiple recursive calls and, finally, receive a response whose length is not 0.

Note: there are plenty of API keys published in [Github](https://github.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.nasa.gov%2Fmars-photos%2Fapi&type=Code) if you want to test the code.

```
var apiKey = "yourApiKey";
var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=";

function requestData(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => {
        if(response.ok) {
            return response.json().then(data => {
                return Promise.resolve(data);
            });
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(response.status);
        }
    });
}

function NasaRequest(sun, limit, frecuency) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var data = await requestData(url + sun + "&api_key=" + apiKey);
        if(data.photos.length === 0 && !limit) {
            setTimeout(async () => {
                console.log("Delay for next request (sun " + sun + "): ", frecuency);
                return await NasaRequest(sun - 1, limit, frecuency);
            }, frecuency);
        } else {
            console.log("Resolve data:", data);    // Code acutally reaches this point
            resolve(data);    // But this doesn't seem to work
        }
    });
};

async function init() {
    try {
        const currentValue = await NasaRequest(2175, false, 2000);
        console.log("currentValue:", currentValue);    // I want to reach this point, but is like the promise never returns
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
}

init();
```

In that moment, I want to return the data in the response to the calling `init()` function, for what I use `resolve(data);`. But it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.then(data => {
                return Promise.resolve(data);
            })` makes no sense, omit it.

Comment: Never pass an `async function` as a callback - not to `new Promise`, not to `setTimeout`. You should only promisify `setTimeout`, and then `await` the timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on `setTimeout`. When you calling `setTimeout` it returns right away and implicitly return `undefined`. The subsequence return doesn't matter at that point. If all you want to do, is to pause, and then proceed try something like this

```js
async function requestData(url) {
    var response = await fetch(url);
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
    } else {
        throw new Error(response.status);
    }
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

async function nasaRequest(sun, limit, freq) {
    var data = await requestData(url + sun + "&api_key=" + apiKey);
    if (data.photos.length === 0 && !limit) {
        await sleep(freq);
        console.log("Delay for next request (sun " + sun + "): ", freq);
        return await nasaRequest(sun - 1, limit, freq);
    } else {
        console.log("Resolve data:", data);
        return data;
    }
};

async function init() {
    try {
        const currentValue = await nasaRequest(2175, false, 2000);
        console.log("currentValue:", currentValue);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

init();
```

I added a simple `sleep` function to handle the pause. I also modified `requestData` (removed `then` and `Promise` parts).
Note that using this recursive approach you may run into stack overflow. To avoid that problem you can simply use a loop and check against your `limit` variable.